# Disable comments from showing up public for Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, comments, rss, private

I have a CPT which supports comments. This CPT is meant for internal use only. However the comments show up in the "Recent comments" default widget. They also show up in the RSS feed.

Is there a simple way to prevent a CPT comments from showing up in widgets, feeds etc.. ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

### Removing Custom Post Types' comments from Recent Comments Widget

The arguments for the recent comments widget can be customized using the `widget_comments_args` filter. To customize the post types types whose comments will be included, we can customize the `$post_type` variable:

> `$post_type` Post type or array of post types to retrieve affiliated comments for.
>   Pass 'any' to match any value. Default empty.

By default, all post types' comments will be included. The following code sets `$post_type` to an array containing only `post` so that only comments from posts will appear. To include additional post types, simply add them to the array.

```
add_action( 'widget_comments_args', 'wpse_widget_comments_args' );
function wpse_widget_comments_args( $args ) {
    $args['post_type'] = [
        'post',
    ];

    return $args;
}
```

### Removing Custom Post Types' comments from the RSS comments feed

This snippet of code (based on solution found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/229152/comments-feed-custom-post-statuses)) will allow you to remove the comments associated with the `book` and `product` post types (as an example) from the RSS comment feed (`http://example.com/comments/feed`). It works by altering the `where` clause of the comments RSS query using the `comment_feed_where` filter.

```
add_filter( 'comment_feed_where', 'wpse_comment_feed_where' );
function wpse_comment_feed_where( $where ) {
    return $where . " AND wp_posts.post_type NOT IN ( 'book', 'product' )";
}
```